# triangle types in python

Tags: python

In order to determine the type of triangle, I must consider the sides by comparing the square of the longest side and the sum of squares of the two smaller sides. If the sum is greater, it is an acute triangle. If they sum is equal, it is a right triangle. If the sum is shorter, it is obtuse.
I must return

- 0  if the three sides cant form a triangle
- 1  if it is an acute triangle
- 2  if it is a righttriangle
- 3  if it is an obtuse triangle

```py
def type_of_triangle(s1, s2, s3):
    if s1 > s2 and s1 > s3:
        if (s2**2 + s3**2) > s1**2:
            return 1
        elif (s2**2 + s3**2) == s1**2: 
            return 2
        elif (s2**2 + s3**2) < s1**2:
            return 3
        elif (s2 + s3) < s1:
            return 0
    if s2 > s1 and s2 > s3:
       if (s1**2 + s3**2) > s2**2:
            return 1
       elif (s1**2 + s3**2) == s2**2: 
            return 2
       elif (s1**2 + s3**2) < s2**2: 
            return 3
       elif (s1 + s3) < s2: 
            return 0
    if s3 > s1 and s3 > s2: 
       if (s1**2 + s2**2) > s3**2: 
            return 1
       elif (s1**2 + s2**2) == s3**2:
            return 2
       elif (s1**2 + s2**2) < s3**2: 
            return 3
       elif (s1 + s2) < s3: 
            return 0
```

any suggestions on the overall code?

Comment: There's a lot of repeated code that could be eliminated if you sorted s1, s2, s3 in order first

Answer (score 1):

There are minor issues with the logic that you are using to determine whether it's an acute triangle or if the sides can't form a triangle. Ypu can simplify the code to make it more concise and easier.

```
def type_triangle(s1, s2, s3):
    sides = sorted([s1, s2, s3])
    if sides[0] + sides[1] <= sides[2]:
        return 0  # Not a triangle

    sum_of_squares = sides[0] ** 2 + sides[1] ** 2
    if sum_of_squares < sides[2] ** 2:
        return 3  # Obtuse triangle
    elif sum_of_squares == sides[2] ** 2:
        return 2  # Right triangle
    else:
        return 1  # Acute triangle

# Examples for testing
print(type_triangle(3, 4, 5))  # Return 2 --> Right triangle
print(type_triangle(5, 12, 13))  # Return 2 --> Right triangle
print(type_triangle(7, 24, 25))  # Return 2 --> Right triangle
print(type_triangle(5, 5, 5))  # Return 1 --> Acute triangle
print(type_triangle(8, 15, 20))  # Return 1 --> Acute triangle
print(type_triangle(3, 4, 7))  # Return 3 --> Obtuse triangle
print(type_triangle(1, 2, 3))  # Return 0 --> Not a triangle
```